# No entiendo como funciona Input

Tags: python, input

Soy relativamente nuevo en este mundo y hay algo que investigue mientras estudio independientemente pero que sinceramente no lo entiendo del todo, ¿como funciona el input?
Por que investigue como se escribe y ciertas funciones, pero a la hora de ponerlo en practica me congelo por que no se como implementarlo, si quiero hacer que la entrada diga algo y funcione para x practica, por ejemplo que se introduzca el nombre o una acción (Ej: un juego), pero sinceramente no entiendo ¿alguien me podría echar una mano? y ¿como deberia practicarlo para que me quede claro? gracias desde ya por leer

Comment: Hola bienvenido a la comunidad. Te sugiero revisar como preguntar: [ask]

Comment: `input` es una `built_in_function` con la cual puedes obtener cualquier dato al usuario por medio de la consola, **siempre** te retorna un string, también acepta un parámetro, que es lo que mostrará por pantalla. No hay nada de complicado en entenderla :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mira. hay muchas maneras de usar un input. voy a tratar de responder tu pregunta con el ejemplo para que diga algo. por ejemplo si estas haciendo programas en terminal, para que el input diga algo (por ejemplo "hola, ingrese un numero") se escribe así

```
x = int(input("Hola, ingrese un numero: "))
```

esto imprimiria por pantalla esto: "Hola, ingrese un numero:"
x es la variable
"int" significa que el valor que se va a escribir a continuacion TIENE que ser un entero, sino da error
"input" crea el input
y por ultimo el texto que dice "ingrese un numero" es lo que se va a imprimir por pantalla. es decir que si cambias lo que esta entre comillas cambia el texto dentro.

espero esto te quite las dudas. te recomiendo mucho el curso de python de [tutorialesprogramacionya](https://tutorialesprogramacionya.com)

Comment: input SIEMPRE devuelve una cadena (palabras, frases, etc). En este escenario int convierte esa cadena en entero. Además, cabe aclarar que si la cadena no se puede transformar a entero (ej: ingresa "1h2") sucederá un error de Python como dices.